# Unable to download blob from Azure Virtual Machine created in the allowed subnet of the Storage Account

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have configured my Storage Account to allow access from a subnet. I created a Virtual machine inside the subnet. I then generated a valid SAS url from my Storage Account for that blob. I used PS Remoting from Azure Cloud Shell to login to the Virtual Machine. In that powershell session, I typed in the following command: curl . I got a 403 Forbidden error.

Note that the endpoint status for the subnet is showing as enabled. When I reviewed the subnet service endpoint, Storage is enabled. The subnet is configured with a network security group with the defaults. The only addition was allowing access for the PS Remoting port.

Why else am I missing to access the blob from the Virtual Machine?

Comment: Can you show the full curl command? or can you try to download blob with Get-[AzureStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblobcontent) on that Azure VM?view=azurermps-6.13.0)? see [more example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-download-azure-blob-storage-using-azure-powershell/)

Comment: @NancyXiong I installed the PS modules for Az.Account and Az.Storage on the VM. I executed a Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication which was successful. I then executed Get-AzStorageAccount. It did not return any storage account which makes me suspect that it cannot connect to the Storage Account. I executed the following with the correct context and got a 403 as well: Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob "ConfigureServer.ps1" -Container "deploy" -Context $ctx

Answer (score 0):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security),

> An application that accesses a storage account when network rules are
>   in effect still requires proper authorization for the request.
>   Authorization is supported with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)
>   credentials for blobs and queues, with a valid account access key, or
>   with an SAS token.

when you access a storage account in the authorized vNet, you still need to provide proper authorization for the request. Please check it on your side. Also, you could allow **trusted Microsoft service** in that exception.